# Read JSON file through Shell Script & replace keys

Tags: json, shell

I am a newbie to Shell Script, I need to **read a local JSON file** through shell script and want to **find & replace all the keys**.

**JSON File**

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

**shell-script.sh**

```
path="./path.json"
# arr=("key1" "key2" "key3")   // this works fine
mapfile -t arr < <(./jq -r 'keys[]' $path) // not working

for elem in "${arr[@]}"
do
sed -i "s/${elem}/MyNewKey/g" $path
done
```

Here, what is the difference between **a hard coded array & the array generated from `mapfile`** utility?

If I echo `arr` in both the ways, both are looks same in console.

Can someone helps me to understand what is the difference?

Comment: What should the output be? You want to replace all keys with the same value? Replace them using `jq` - parse json files with json-aware parsers.

Comment: Do you get any errros?  Are you using a shell that has support for arrays and mapfile?  Why are you using a version of `jq` from the current directory?  Why are you using `sed -i`?!! Are the keys literally "key1", "key2", and "key3", or might they contain unusual characters (eg `/`)?  Why don't you just do `echo '{ "MyNewKey": "value3" }' > "$path"`?  The net effect of replacing all the keys with the same key is to discard most of them (assuming you want the output to be valid json).

Comment: @WilliamPursell No errors. Yes I use the shell script that supports arrays and mapfile. I have added `jq` in $PATH, so it is available in current directory. `sed -i` command can be used for find & replace. They never contain any special characters, literally `key1`, `key2` & `key3`. Not replacing with same key, will replace with `MyNewKey1`, `MyNewKey2` & `MyNewKey3`, index can be added, so it will be valid json.

Literally problem is, when I use a string directly, it is replacing. But If I bind a variable, it is not replacing. Did you get me?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed -i "s/$elem/MyNewKey/g" $path`

You have to reference elem that way, because its not an array. It is a specific element of your array. Generally you reference a for-loop variable by putting a $ infront of it.

For simple examples regarding for loops i found [this](https://www.shellscript.sh/loops.html) to be helpful.

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: I see. I have updated my answer. I hope this shows what I did to fix OPs code.

Comment: @RyanNerd Thank you for the answer. I have tried this solution, no luck. Was it working for you? Are you able to reproduce my issue?

Comment: I think, the problem is with usage of `mapfile`, instead of generating keys array in such a way, If I hard code like `arr=("key1" "key2" "key3")` it works.